# Infinite Recursion with JSON and Hibernate JPA

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring-boot, input

Using spring Boot , When trying to get JPA object into JSON, I keep getting this error :

```
nested exception is 
  `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
     Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); 
    nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.
JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)
 (through reference chain: interv.Entities.AppUser["projects"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->interv.Entities.Project["appUser"]->interv.Entities.AppUser["projects"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.Persis`
```

following some solution in stack overflow i ended by adding the annotation 
 @JsonIgnoreProperties , so my entity Project  looks like this :

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Project implements Serializable{

        @Id @GeneratedValue
        private long id;
        private String intitule;
        private String description;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project" , fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
       @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
        @JsonIgnoreProperties("contrats")
        private Collection<Contrat> contrats;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "Id_appUser")
        @JsonIgnoreProperties("appUser")
        private AppUser appUser;
 }
```

the api restful looks like this :

```
    import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class ProjectsController {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectRepo projectRepo;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/ListProjects", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Project> getProjects(){
        return projectRepo.findAll();
    }
```

i tried other annotations but i keep getting the same error :

in ARC extention i get :

200 OK

There was an error parsing JSON data

Unexpected end of JSON input

thank you in advance for your help :) .

EDIT :

the file AppUser.java

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
public class AppUser implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<AppRole> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "appUser" , fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private Collection<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>();


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "appUser" , fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private Collection<Intervention> interventions = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "appUser" , fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private Collection<Contrat> contrats = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Comment: As per the error message the chain is continuing infinitely because of appUser property. Try adding @JsonIgnoreProperties at class level including both contracts and appUser properties.

Comment: @K.SivaPrasadReddy thank you for help first , i've added the annotation JsonIgnoreProperties to the propertie appUser also as i mentioned in the post but i keep getting the same error , is it the way you told me to do ?

Comment: @what do you mean by adding it at class level ?

Comment: @dEs12ZER The AppUser contains a List of Project???

Comment: @SEY_91 yes the Entity AppUser containts a Collection of Projects

Comment: Maybe it will be helpful: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems occurs because there is an infinite loop when generating the JSON. You can use @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference to solve the Infinite recursion.

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Project implements Serializable{

        @Id @GeneratedValue
        private long id;
        private String intitule;
        private String description;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project" , fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
       @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
        @JsonIgnoreProperties("contrats")
        private Collection<Contrat> contrats;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "Id_appUser")
        @JsonBackReference
        private AppUser appUser;
 }
```

AppUser

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
public class AppUser implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<AppRole> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "appUser" , fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Collection<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>();


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "appUser" , fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private Collection<Intervention> interventions = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "appUser" , fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private Collection<Contrat> contrats = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Comment: i did exactly what you proposed but i get this error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.Collection) not compatible with managed type (interv.Entities.Project)

Comment: the same error while using List instead of collection

Comment: Sorry my bad, `@JsonManagedReference` must be applied on the collection, see now if it works.

Comment: YOU SAVED MY DAY !! thank you so much it works now !!